# Npgsql - BulkCopy from ConcurrentQueue<T>

Tags: bulkinsert, npgsql

Let's say I have a method like this:

```
public async Task BulkCopy(ConcurrentQueue<Model> modelQueue, string connectionString)
{
    while(modelQueue.IsEmpty == false)
    {
        try
        {
            using(NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();

                using(var writer = connection.BeginBinaryImport("COPY myTable (Id,Name,Something,SomethingElse)"))
                {
                    // Is this what I'm supposed to do?
                    foreach(Model item in modelQueue)
                    {
                        writer.WriteRow(item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Model has properties Guid Id, string Name, string Something, string SomethingElse(just like the table).

Can I use WriteRow() and pass in an entire object? Is this implementation way to go or I am doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is pretty simple, since ConcurrentQueue implements IEnumerable all I had to do is run through the queue and write the data.

```
public async Task BulkCopy(ConcurrentQueue<Model> modelQueue, string connectionString)
{
    while(modelQueue.IsEmpty == false)
    {
        try
        {
            using(NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();

                using(var writer = connection.BeginBinaryImport("COPY myTable (Id,Name,Something,SomethingElse) FROM STDIN (FORMAT BINARY)"))
                {
                    foreach(Model item in modelQueue)
                    {
                        writer.StartRow();
                        writer.Write(item.Id, NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Uuid);
                        writer.Write(item.Name);
                        writer.Write(item.Something);
                        writer.Write(item.SomethingElse);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to do the job. The time needed for 30000 records is average 540ms.